# Exception: "There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

In the BizTalk Console Administration I often see exceptions like the following:

> There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline: "[pipelineName], [BizTalk projectName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35805574d24305bf" Source: "Unknown " Send Port: "[sendPortName]" URI: "[sqlServerConnString]" Reason: Failed to get pipeline: [pipelineName], [BizTalk projectName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35805574d24305bf. Please verify that the pipeline strong name is correct and that the pipeline assembly is in the GAC.

I think the problem is how I deployed the pipeline and the project because I have developed my solution on a Virtual Machine (that have Visual Studio) and then I deployed my solution on another Virtual Machine (that does not have Visual Studio installed).
For the deploy I put the dll needed in a folder and then I added them from BizTalk Administration tool (Resources). Another strange thing I noticed is that in Resources I have:

> [pipelineName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=netrual, PublicKeyToken=60cf10bb1a125a7
>
> [BizTalk projectName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=netrual, PublicKeyToken=35805574d24305bf

I have no idea how to solve this issue. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check:

- **pipelineName** is a pipeline inside the project (and the DLL)

[BizTalk projectName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=netrual, PublicKeyToken=35805574d24305bf

- Your DLL **have to be in the GAC**, please check that the DLL is in the GAC, If not, add the DLL from BizTalk Administration tool (Resources) with "Add to the global assembly cache on add resource (gacutil)" option checked.
- On resources you only need this:

[BizTalk projectName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=netrual, PublicKeyToken=35805574d24305bf

The other one ([pipelineName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=netrual, PublicKeyToken=60cf10bb1a125a7) is another DLL that you added to this BizTalk application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly deploy the Pipeline Component Assembly.

This article explains the entire process: [BizTalk Server: Deploying Custom Pipeline Components in BizTalk Server 2006 and Higher](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26404.biztalk-server-deploying-custom-pipeline-components-in-biztalk-server-2006-and-higher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the associated hosts and the standard BizTalkServerApplication host to refresh the in-memory data.

Comment: Usually only necessary if the DLL has been deployed previously and you have made a change.  But yes, good practice to restart the host instances after a deployment.